# codeigniter active record query using two order by

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new in CI, and I have a question..

My normal sql is:

```
$tb1 = 'se_avg';
$tb2 = 'se_school';

$sql_top = "(SELECT * FROM $tb1 ,$tb2 WHERE $tb1.sid = $tb2.sid AND gid = '$gid' AND avg_mark > $s_mark  AND $tb1.year = '2014' ORDER BY avg_mark ASC LIMIT 0 , 20) ORDER BY vg_mark DESC";
```

I wanna rewrite it in CI active record.

But I have no idea to put another order by outside this sql：

```
$sql_top = "(SELECT * FROM $tb1 ,$tb2 WHERE $tb1.sid = $tb2.sid AND gid = '$gid' AND avg_mark > $s_mark  AND $tb1.year = '2014' ORDER BY avg_mark ASC LIMIT 0 , 20)
```

Now, my CI active record is:

```
$tb1 = 'se_avg';
$tb2 = 'se_school';

$sql_top = $this->db
           ->select('*')
           ->from($tb1)
           ->join($tb2, "$tb1.sid = $tb2.sid", 'left')
           ->where('gid', $gid)
           ->where('avg_mark >', $s_mark)
           ->where("$tb1.year", '2014')
           ->order_by("avg_mark", 'asc')
           ->limit(20, 0);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Where can I add order_by(("avg_mark", 'desc')?

I've try to put it after limit, but I get wrong data...

Maybe there's another way?

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to order the results by `avg_mark` ascending and descending?

Comment: um...yes.

First, I order the results by $tb1.avg_mark ascending, then I'll order the results by $tb1.avg_mark descending.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you're going to order by the same thing ascending and then descending its the same thing as ordering the query by descending (since this is a single query).  If you want to get two separate sets of results then write two queries, otherwise this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Here http://bit.ly/1odnmRu

Answer (score 0):

- make the following changes in the query and you will get the desired result
- change which table contains `avg_mark`

**->order_by('$tb1.avg_mark', 'DESC')**

Comment: oh!sorry, I didn't write it clearly.
avg_mark is just from $tb1, not came from both table